# Use hashed password from /etc/shadow to encrypt files

Tags: python

Looking to use hashed password from /etc/shadow to encrypt files. Trying with Python 2.7. Existing code is using Crypto.Cipher/Hash but asks for the user input for the password. From what I could read about spwd I could just verify if the entered password matches the hash correctly but I want to use the hash and not ask the user for a password at all.

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import os, random, sys

from os import path

def encrypt(key, filename, outFile):
    chunksize = 64 * 1024
    filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
    IV = ''

    for i in range(16):
            IV += chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF))

    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

    with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
        with open(outFile, "wb") as outfile:
            outfile.write(filesize)
            outfile.write(IV)
            while True:
                    chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                    if len(chunk) == 0:
                            break

                    elif len(chunk) % 16 !=0:
                            chunk += ' ' *  (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))

                    outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))

def decrypt(key, filename, outFile):
    chunksize = 64 * 1024

    with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
            filesize = infile.read(16)
            IV = infile.read(16)

            decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

            with open(outFile, "wb") as outfile:
                    while True:
                            chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                            if len(chunk) == 0:
                                    break

                            outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))

                    outfile.truncate(int(filesize))

BASE_PATH = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))

choice = raw_input("Do you want to (E)ncrypt or (D)ecrypt? ")
encFiles = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'your_file_name') 

typed_out_file = raw_input('Enter out file_name: ')
outFile = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, typed_out_file) 
password = raw_input("Enter the password: ")  


if choice == "E":

    if os.path.basename(encFiles).startswith("(encrypted)"):
            print "%s is already encrypted" %str(Tfiles)
            pass

    elif encFiles == os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sys.argv[0]):
            pass 
    else:
            encrypt(SHA256.new(password).digest(), str(encFiles), outFile)
            print "Done encrypting %s" %str(encFiles)
            os.remove(encFiles)


elif choice == "D":

    filename = raw_input("Enter the filename to decrypt: ")
    out_file = raw_input("Enter the new filename: ")

    decrypt(SHA256.new(password).digest(), filename, out_file)
    print "Done decrypting %s" %filename
    os.remove(filename)

else:
    print "Please choose a valid command."
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: First off, the code snipped in the question does not read from /etc/shadow, this code looks like it is called after the key (the hashed password) is extracted. Secondly, not every user has a password, if the root user on your system doesn't have a password set, their password will be empty in /etc/shadow. Finally, there is at least one bug in the code snippet you posted and I would strongly encourage you to use a pre-built tool to encrypt your files.

Comment: I added all of the code. I do not have anything defined here to look at /etc/shadow or use spwd. I am going to be using the root account that has a password already set during the build process.

Comment: Hi @asolak, I would really like to help you but I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. Python doesn't have a build process. Also you usually want your cryptographic keys to be either generated randomly or derived from a password using something like PKDF2.

Comment: @tantalum - Maybe ignore the code while I phrase it this way. I just want to encrypt some file(s) using a hash of a password (like that found in /etc/shadow)